# Get quotients and remainder from division of floats

Tags: python

What is the Pythonic approach to getting a quotients and remainder from division of **floats**? So taking 8 divided by 3 which is 2.66666666666

so I want:

```
aPythonOperator(8,3) = 2.0, 0.66666666666
```

but I cannot find a clean way of doing this without the remainder being rounded.
For completeness the Python division operators are:

```
import math
a = 8.0
b = 3.0
print(f'Division:{a/b}')
print(f'Floored division: {a//b}')
print(f'Modulo: {a%b}')
print(f'Remainder: {math.remainder(a,b)}')  # rounds to int and yields -1 (?)
print(f'Divmod: {divmod(a, b)}')
```

which gives:

```
Division:2.6666666666666665
Floored division: 2.0
Modulo: 2.0
Remainder: -1.0
```

These don't help, but I expected the Divmod function to work. However, Divmod rounds the quotient to an int:

```
print(f'Divmod: {divmod(a, b)}')
Divmod: (2.0, 2.0)
```

I can get the behaviour I want by creating my own version of the Divmod function:

```
def hackDivmod(a,b):  
    #HACK
    Div = (a/b)
    floredDiv = (a//b) 
    return floredDiv,  Div-floredDiv
```

This works as desired:

```
HackDivmod: (2.0, 0.6666666666666665)
```

But is there a better way do doing this using built in functions or operators?

Comment: It's not exactly that divmod is rounding, it's that divmod returns a tuple `(quotient, remainder)`, whereas what you want is `(int part of quotient, fractional part of quotient)`.

Comment: If you're doing float division, there is no remainder.  It's sounds like what you actually want are the whole and fractional parts of the float? Just to clarify, if you were doing a=14 and b=3, would you be looking for 4.0 and 0.66666666... ?

Comment: `math.modf(8.0/3.0)` gives `(0.6666666666666665, 2.0)`, so that's almost what you need. You can just do `[::-1]` to reverse the order if you prefer.

Comment: yes: HackDivmod: (4.0, 0.666666666666667)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want to use [`math.modf()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.modf) combined with native division

```
>>> import math
>>> math.modf( 8 / 3)
(0.6666666666666665, 2.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
def divfract(a, b):
    return a // b, (a % b) / b
```

This returns the same result as your 'hack' function (which is actually also perfectly fine), including for negative numbers (e.g `divfract(-8, 3) == (-3, 0.333...)`), whereas `math.modf` rounds the other way `(-2, -0.666...)`. (There are [different ways to calculate a remainder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285497/python-modulus-the-same-as-remainder))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `math.modf()` to get two separate portions. It is a built in method to split a number into integer and decimal parts. You can use the following custom `myDivMod()` function is order to make it work as following:

```
import math
def myDivMod(myParam, myDiv):
    fraction, wholeNum = math.modf( myParam / myDiv)
    return fraction, wholeNum

a,b = myDivMod(8,3)
print(a,b) # output is 0.6666666666666665, 2.0
```

I hope this solves your issue